# Find the root in the form $a+bi$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

$(2-i)z^2-(1+i)z+1$, with $z=i$ as a root. There's supposed to be another root in the form of $a+bi$.

When I factorised it, it became $(z-i)[(2-i)z+i]$, which looks nothing like the $a+bi$ form.

Did I factorise it incorrectly?

Comment: if you find one root, you can always use sum/product of roots of a quadratic to find the 2nd root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

Let $(2-i)z+i = 0$

Solve for $z$.

Multiplying the conjugate of the denominator of a fraction to both the numerator and denominator helps.

Comment: Right; thank you! I didn't see that earlier.